# What is wrong in the system call

Tags: visual-c++, system-calls

I've been trying the next code in Visual Studio 2022 :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Command1 = "cmd /c start ";
    string Command2 = "\"c:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\"";
    string myCommand = Command1 + Command2;
    //cout << myCommand;
    system(myCommand.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the command line "cmd /c start c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" to be executed end the program vlc is going to run.
It seems that not te complete command is given.

I don't know what i doing wrong.

Comment: remove `start`, just pass path to executable

Comment: Yes, but then the original window does not close, and that is precisely the intention.

Comment: Consider a more robust alternative like `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I did wrong,
I forgot to add quotes in the rule  "string Command = "cmd /c start ";".
The syntax from 'start' is: start "" <program.exe>

The complete program in c++ that does work is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Command1 = "cmd /c start \"\" ";
    string Command2 = "\"c:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\"";
    string myCommand = Command1 + Command2;
    system(myCommand.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```